# how to disable message "You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger..."?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm running Visual Studio Code 1.42.1 on Ubuntu 19.10, using the default C# extension version 1.21.11.

Whenever I launch a C# program using "Start Debugging", or even via "Run Without Debugging", I see this message in the output window:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This message is annoying.  Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: That's part of the licensing terms of the debugger, so you have to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this problem you can change something in your launch.json file

1. Open .vscode/launch.json
2. Change the console setting to integratedTerminal

From:
`"console": "internalConsole",`

To:
`"console": "integratedTerminal",`

3. Save your change and start debugging your project

This works pretty good for me

Answer (score -1):

Delete .vscode, now your debugger automatic default