# in vscode how to disable message in debug console "You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger..."?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Whenever I launch a C# program using "Start Debugging", or "Run Without Debugging", I see this message in the output window:

---

### You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.

it is annoying, solution from here [how to disable message "You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247398/how-to-disable-message-you-may-only-use-the-microsoft-net-core-debugger) is not working

when I edit launch.json file and change console settings like in the linked solution 2 things happen:

1 "console": "internalConsole"
in the debugger console i get the message from above + the result of my program

2 "console": "integratedTerminal"
here I only get the message

in both cases debug console automatically opens after the program finishes executing

how to remove the message completely or remove the automatic opening debug console so that the terminal or output are opened automatically where there is no message?

Comment: There is a comment to the other question which says that it cannot be disabled.

Comment: Can you clarify what distinguishes your question from the one you have linked?